# pickerview app crashing due to NSRangeException NSCFArray objectAtIndex: index (5)...beyond bounds (5)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, exception, uipickerview

Once again working through beginning iphone development and I am putting together a bunch of UIPicker type apps, the last one of which is a slot machine type of game, super simple. Anyway  I am not really understanding why this error is coming up. to my understanding the picker view is asking its delegate for an object in the array that is past the range available to that array.

That being said I have no idea why it is doing this or how to fix it, any help would be appreciated, heres the code from the particular .m file( get the full project here: http://files.me.com/knyck2/89q3w3 ):

```
 //
 //  CustomPickerViewController.m
 //  Pickers
 //
 //  Created by Nicholas Iannone on 1/29/10.
 //  Copyright 2010 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
 //

 #import "CustomPickerViewController.h"


 @implementation CustomPickerViewController

 @synthesize column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, picker, winLabel;

 -(IBAction) spin : (id) sender {

NSLog(@"even got here");

BOOL win = NO;

int numInRow = 1;

int lastVal = -1;

for (int i = 0; 1 < 5; i++) {
    int newValue = random() % [self.column1 count];

    if (newValue == lastVal) {
        NSLog(@"even got here");

    numInRow++;
    }
    else 
        numInRow = 1;

        lastVal = newValue;
    [picker selectRow:newValue inComponent:i animated:YES];
    [picker reloadComponent:i];
    if (numInRow >= 3) 
        win = YES;

    NSLog(@"even got here");

}

if (win) 
    winLabel.text = @"winner!";

              else {
    winLabel.text = @"";
              NSLog(@"even got here");
              }

 }

 /*
  // The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically                and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
 }
 */


 // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from      a nib.
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
UIImage *seven = [UIImage imageNamed:@"seven.png"];
UIImage *bar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar.png"];
UIImage *crown = [UIImage imageNamed:@"crown.png"];
UIImage *cherry = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cherry.png"];
UIImage *lemon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lemon.png"];
UIImage *apple = [UIImage imageNamed:@"apple.png"];

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5 ;  i++) {
        UIImageView *sevenView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: seven];
        UIImageView *barView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: bar];
        UIImageView *crownView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: crown];
        UIImageView *cherryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:      cherry];
        UIImageView *lemonView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: lemon];
        UIImageView *appleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: apple];


        NSArray *imageViewArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:      sevenView, barView, crownView, cherryView, lemonView, appleView, nil];
        NSString *fieldName =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"column%d",      i];
        [self setValue:imageViewArray forKey:fieldName];
        [fieldName release];
        [imageViewArray release];

        [sevenView release];
        [crownView release];
        [barView release];
        [cherryView release];
        [lemonView release];
        [appleView release];

    }

srandom(time(NULL));
[super viewDidLoad];
 }



 /*
 // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }
 */

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
 }

 - (void)viewDidUnload {
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
 }


 - (void)dealloc {
[picker release];
[winLabel release];
[column1 release];
[column2 release];
[column3 release];
[column4 release];
[column5 release];


[super dealloc];
 }


 #pragma mark -
 #pragma mark Picker Data Source Methods

 -(NSInteger) numberOfComponentsInPickerView: (UIPickerView *)  pickerView {

return 5;
 }


 -(NSInteger) pickerView: (UIPickerView *) pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:      (NSInteger) component {

return [self.column1 count];

 }

 #pragma mark Picker Delegate Methods

 -(UIView *) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent: (NSInteger) component reusingView : (UIView *)view {

NSString *arrayName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"column%d", component + 1];
NSArray *array = [self valueForKey:arrayName];
NSLog(@"got here yo");
return [array objectAtIndex: row];
NSLog(@"holyshit");


 }

 @end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it's breaking is this loop.  Take a look at your for loop condition:

`1 < 5`.  Yes, 1 is *always* less than 5.  This means that you have an infinite loop.  I'm sure you meant `i < 5`.

```
for (int i = 0; 1 < 5; i++) {
    int newValue = random() % [self.column1 count];

    if (newValue == lastVal) {
        NSLog(@"even got here");

    numInRow++;
    }
    else 
        numInRow = 1;

        lastVal = newValue;
    [picker selectRow:newValue inComponent:i animated:YES];
    [picker reloadComponent:i];
    if (numInRow >= 3) 
        win = YES;

    NSLog(@"even got here");

}
```

Comment: ugh, thanks so much, i don't think i would have ever found that, lol.

Comment: do you have any idea why the uipickerview would not animate to the selected row, even though the animated argument is set to"YES"?

Answer (score 2):

You're testing if `1 < 5`, which is always true. You want `i < 5`.